# Design sequential circuit with 3 state buffer

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, buffer

I asked to design a sequential circuit with 3 state buffer so when :

Load = 1 -> put data into output

Load = 0 -> don't change output

Here is my design:

[image]

But question said also use other gates.

Is this design wrong?

Comment: Please use the built-in schematic editor.

Comment: define  tri state output control and input latch controls either edge or state controlled Output must have 3 states and 1 input and 2 controls

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't understand, all I know about 3 states buffer is that when ctrl is on they will work and otherwise they will cut off the branch

Comment: @Eugene sh. I don't know how to use them but I'll try to learn, thanks : )

Comment: Please tell us exactly what the question said. What does your instructor want from you?

Comment: Design a sequential circuit with three-state buffer using above conditions (hint: use 2 three-state buffer and other logical gastes), that's the exact question